# Accessing ethernet device with duplicate ip in separate namespaces

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

my apologies if this question has been asked somewhere. I've been searching for days and have tried many different things but I am still missing something.

### The problem

I have to connect to multiple devices, 2 at the same time with an IP 192.168.240.120/24. The other devices are in the 169.254.x.x/16 and 192.168.1.x/24 range and will only be connecting to these one at a time. These IPs are set from the manufacturer and cannot be changed. Currently, I have all the functionality I need except for being able to connect to 2 devices with the same IP at once.

### **The goal**

I wish to be able to access both devices with the same IP of 192.168.240.120/24 at the same time. **One device on eth0 and the other on eth1**. All other devices will be accessed on eth0 one at a time. They do not need internet access through wlan0.

1. Plug in device1 (192.168.240.120) to eth0, access device at 192.168.15.1, configure
2. Plug in device2 (192.168.240.120) to eth1, access device at 192.168.15.2, configure
3. disconnect both devices (eth0, eth1)
4. Plug in device3 (169.254.1.5) to eth0, access device at 192.168.15.1, configure
5. Disconnect eth0 device
6. Repeat 4-5 for the rest of the devices

### What I have done

To be able to connect to all the devices on eth0 I have set multiple IP addresses for that interface. I also switched from dhcpcd to NetworkManager because I could not get dhcpcd to work properly with link-local addresses.

```
sudo ip addr add 192.168.240.121/24 dev eth0
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.2/24 dev eth0
sudo ip addr add 169.254.1.3/16 dev eth0
sudo ip addr add 169.254.2.1/16 dev eth0
```

This works great when I don't need to connect to both devices with the same IP. After many days of searching I stumbled upon this and thought it was exactly what I needed: 
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/38572

So I spent more days looking up how to create namespaces and how to add veth, bridges, and physical ethernet ports to them. I was able to ping the veth inside of the namespace1 and namespace2 from the default namespace but could not figure out how to route an IP to the eth0 and eth1 devices. I got frustrated trying to understand how to route it so I kept searching. Commands I ran for this are setup are below.

Here is the youtube video I was following along with: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_UUnlVC2Ss

```bash
# Enable ip forwarding
sudo echo -e "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" >> /etc/sysctl.d/custom.conf

# Create namespaces
sudo ip netns add ns-eth0
sudo ip netns add ns-eth1

# Add ethernet devices to their namespaces
sudo ip link set eth0 netns ns-eth0
sudo ip link set eth1 netns ns-eth1

# Bring loopbacks up
sudo ip netns exec ns-eth0 ip link set dev lo up
sudo ip netns exec ns-eth1 ip link set dev lo up

# Create bridge for namespaces
sudo ip link add eth-bridge type bridge
sudo ip link set dev eth-bridge up

# Create veth pairs for new namespaces
sudo ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth0-br
sudo ip link add veth1 type veth peer name veth1-br

# Attach veth to namespaces
sudo ip link set veth0 netns ns-eth0
sudo ip link set veth1 netns ns-eth1

# Attach veth-br to the bridge
sudo ip link set veth0-br master eth-bridge
sudo ip link set veth1-br master eth-bridge

# Set veth ip's in their namespaces
sudo ip -n ns-eth0 addr add 192.168.15.10/24 dev veth0
sudo ip -n ns-eth1 addr add 192.168.15.11/24 dev veth1

# Set ip's for physical eth devices
sudo ip -n ns-eth0 addr add 192.168.1.2/24 dev eth0
sudo ip -n ns-eth0 addr add 192.168.255.130/24 dev eth0
sudo ip -n ns-eth0 addr add 169.254.1.3/16 dev eth0
sudo ip -n ns-eth0 addr add 169.254.2.1/16 dev eth0
sudo ip -n ns-eth1 addr add 192.168.255.130 dev eth1

# Bring veths up
sudo ip -n ns-eth0 link set veth0 up
sudo ip -n ns-eth1 link set veth1 up

# Give the bridge an ip
sudo ip addr add 192.168.15.254/24 dev eth-bridge
```

After searching I came across IPVLANs and MACVLANs. From my understanding, since I am connected to the router via wlan0 I am unable to use MACVLANS, which brings me to IPVLANS. After searching up on how to create one, I came across a quick video on how to set one up. I am not sure which option would be best in my case, but it seems as though an IPVLAN is less complicated based on the video. 
Here is the video I am referring to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CtnWyrRvG4

Here is how it is configured:

```bash
ip link add link wlan0 name ipnet1 type ipvlan mode l3
ip link add link wlan0 name ipnet2 type ipvlan mode l3
ip netns add ns1
ip netns add ns2
ip link set dev ipnet1 netns ns1
ip link set dev ipnet2 netns ns2
ip -n ns1 link set ipnet1 up
ip -n ns1 addr add 192.168.15.1/32 dev ipnet1
ip -n ns2 addr add 192.168.15.2/32 dev ipnet2
ip -n ns2 link set ipnet2 up
ip -n ns1 route add default dev ipnet1
ip -n ns2 route add default dev ipnet2
ip netns exec ns1 ping 192.168.15.2 # successful
ip netns exec ns2 ping 192.168.15.1 # successful
ip link add link wlan0 name ipnet0 type ipvlan mode l3
ip link set dev ipnet0 up
ip addr add 192.168.15.5/32 dev ipnet0
ip route add 192.168.15.1/32 dev ipnet0
ip netns exec ns1 ping 192.168.137.42 # successful
ip netns exec ns1 ping 192.168.15.5 # successful
ping 192.168.15.1 # successful
ip route add 192.168.15.2/32 dev ipnet0
ping 192.168.15.2 # successful

# Now to add physical eth to namespace
ip link set eth0 netns ns1
ip link set eth1 netns ns2
ip -n ns1 route del default
ip -n ns2 route del default
ip -n ns1 link set eth0 up
ip -n ns2 link set eth1 up
ip -n ns1 route add default dev eth0
ip -n ns2 route add default dev eth1
ip -n ns2 addr add 192.168.240.121/24 dev eth1
ip -n ns1 addr add 192.168.1.2/24 dev eth0
ip -n ns1 addr add 169.254.1.3/16 dev eth0
ip -n ns1 addr add 169.254.2.1/16 dev eth0
```

Once I set the default route in the nsX to `default dev ethX` I am no longer able to ping and there is no communication to the device connected to ethX. I've spent too long trying to troubleshoot and I really need some help.

**NOTE: I know many of you may have the thought "Then get different equipment" but that is not a possibility. These devices will be accessed in-band on fiber links and the local management port is disabled once the config is loaded.**

**EDIT: I will reply as soon as I can. When I created an account it did not link it to this question, so I am unable to reply until support resolves the issue.**

Comment: Do these devices support IPv6?

Comment: Could you use a VM to access one and the physical to access the other? with perhaps a static arp entry for the desired host?

Comment: @harrymc I don't believe they support IPv6 on the local management ports. I know it is supported on the fiber ports though.

Comment: @uSlackr Unfortunately not. This is a raspberry pi 4 and with the limited resources I am unable to use a VM.

Comment: I don't fully understand the difference between ports. but if there is an IPv6 address, you could try to access it on the local ports. It would be easy to disable IPv6 on one network adapter and disable IPv4 on the other.